# Place Two Font Awesome Icons Next to Each Other in an Unordered List

Tags: html-lists, font-awesome

I use Font Awesome icons (Version 6 Free) in a project
I want to place two Font Awesome icons, for example an A and a 1 next to each other in a unordered list. I use this HTML code:

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
    <li><i class="fa-li fa-solid fa-a"></i><i class="fa-li fa-solid fa-1"></i>List item</li> 
</ul>
```

However, using this code the two icons are placed on top of each other. I know how you can stack icons, but not how to place them next to each other. Any pointers to set me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li>
    <span class="fa-li">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-a" data-fa-transform="left-10"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-1" data-fa-transform="right-10"></i>
    </span>
    List item
  </li> 
</ul>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Of course the span element can accomplish this feat.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.